# Entity framework nested query

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I'm new to LINQ and I want to write the simplest nested query.

I have two lists of objects: Clients and Orders.

```
public class Client
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int Name{ get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int ClientId{ get; set; }
   public Client Client{ get; set; }
   public DateTime DateOfOrder{ get; set; }
}
```

I would like to get the clients who had orders in the last 6 months.
In SQL it would be:

```
SELECT * FROM CLIENTS WHERE ClientId IN 
(SELECT ClientId FROM ORDERS WHERE DateOfOrder>'2020-01-01')
```

I assume that I need to use "Contains", but I do not know how to return a list of ClientIds instead of a list of Orders.

```
var clients=db.Clients.Where(c=>db.Orders.Where(a=>a.DateOfOrder>DateTime.Now.AddDays(-183).ToList().Contains(c.ClientId)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `ToList` and use `Select` in the inner query. Something like this:

```
var clients = db.Clients 
   .Where(c => db.Orders
      .Where(a => a.DateOfOrder > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-183))
      .Select(a => a.ClientId)
      .Contains(c.ClientId))
   .ToList();
```